# Proving that $\alpha<\beta $ two zeros of non-nul solution of $y''(x)+q_2(x) y(x)=0$ vanish in $[\alpha,\beta]$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

let $I\subset \mathbb{R}, q_1,q_2: I\to \mathbb{R}$ and $q_1, q_2$ are two continuous function such that $q_1(x) \geq q_2(x)$ ,$\forall{x}\in \mathbb{R}$, let $\alpha< \beta$ two zeros of non nul solution of the following ODE:
$y''(x)+q_2(x) y(x)=0$, I want to show that every solution of $y''(x)+q_1(x) y(x)=0$ vanish in $[\alpha,\beta]$?

**Attempt:** I have $\alpha< \beta$ two zeros of non always vanishing solution of the following ODE:
$y''(x)+q_2(x) y(x)=0$ this means that  $y(\alpha)=y(\beta)=0$ which yield to study property of the value boundary problem defined as :$$(P)\begin{cases}y''(x)+q_2(x) y(x)=0\\y(\alpha)=y(\beta)=0 \end{cases}$$  from $y(\alpha)=y(\beta)=0$ this means that there exist $c \in [\alpha,\beta]$  such that: $y'(c)=0 $ using Role Theorem , I subdivised the $[\alpha,\beta]$ as $[\alpha,0]$ and $[0,\beta]$, In $[\alpha,0]$ we have  for $x\in \mathbb{R}$: $q_1(x) \geq q_2(x)$  this means that $q_1$ is a continious decreasing function in $[\alpha,0]$ , I'm really mixed in this step for using intermediate value theorem to show that there exist $x_0\in [\alpha,\beta]$ such that $y(x_0)=0$.

Any idea ? Or any simple way to show that  every non nul solution of $(P)$ vanish in $[\alpha,\beta]$ ?

Comment: See [Sturm’s comparison theorem](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~siva/ma41707/ode8.pdf) in paragraph 7.2.

Comment: You mean "vanish at some point in $[α,β]$", not be identically zero on that interval.

Comment: Please read and correct your proof attempt. I'm quite sure you mean to say $y_2$ instead of $q_2$ in several places, and $c$ or better $γ$ instead of $0$ in the intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to make additional assumptions, such that the $y_2$ solution has no other roots inside the interval, thus a unique sign. You can even demand $y_2'(α)=1>0$ so that $y_2$ is non-negative and concave on the interval. This then implies that $y_2'$ has a unique root $γ$ inside the interval, and that then indeed $y_2$ is increasing on $[α,γ]$ and decreasing on $[γ,β]$.

Now assume that there is a solution $y_1$ of $y''+q_1y=0$ that is positive over all of the interval. The key then is to consider the Wronskian-like expression
$$
w(x)=y_1(x)y_2'(x)-y_1'(x)y_2(x).
$$
Immediately $w(α)=y_1(α)>0$. Then due to its structure
$$
w'(x)=y_1(x)y_2''(x)-y_1''(x)y_2(x)=(q_1(x)-q_2(x))y_1(x)y_2(x).
$$
Inside the interval all the factors on the right are positive, so that $w$ is increasing and thus stays positive. But
$$
0<w(β)=y_1(β)y_2'(β)
$$
is a contradiction, as $y_2'(β)<0$.